# "botocore.exceptions.ClientError: security token included in the request is invalid" when running containerized app, while it works locally

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, docker, authentication, flask

I want to run my application in a Docker container. It runs very well locally. Unfortunately, I have a problem with my security token, it seems I'm not authenticated correctly or something.

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the CreateTable operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

Here is the error message that Docker returns when running this app:

```
(venv) (base) remplacement@remplacements-MacBook-Pro flask-login % docker run -p 5000:5000 -v ~/.aws/credentials:/root/.aws/credentials sum_up_app

 * Serving Flask app 'app.py'
 * Debug mode: off
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
 * Running on http://172.17.0.2:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
[2023-10-02 09:33:14,088] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/utils.py", line 66, in get_existant_summaries
    summaries = table.scan()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 580, in do_action
    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/boto3/resources/action.py", line 88, in __call__
    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(*args, **params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 530, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 964, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the Scan operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "/app/app.py", line 55, in index
    summaries = get_existant_summaries(user_id)
  File "/app/utils.py", line 68, in get_existant_summaries
    create_dynamodb_table('summaries')
  File "/app/utils.py", line 106, in create_dynamodb_table
    table = dynamodb.create_table(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 580, in do_action
    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/boto3/resources/action.py", line 88, in __call__
    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(*args, **params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 530, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 964, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the CreateTable operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

The error seems to come from this one:

`utils.py`

```
import openai
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader
from docx import Document
import boto3
import csv
import logging
from datetime import datetime, date
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import os
from decouple import config


UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'uploads'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'zip'}


# Lisez les variables d'environnement AWS en utilisant python-decouple
aws_access_key_id = config('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
aws_secret_access_key = config('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
aws_region = config('AWS_REGION')

# # Configurez le client AWS avec les informations d'environnement
# session = boto3.Session(
#     aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
#     aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key,
#     region_name=aws_region
# )

# from pymongo import MongoClient
def get_credentials_from_csv(file_path):
    credentials = {}
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file)
        for row in reader:
            credentials['aws_access_key_id'] = row['aws_access_key_id']
            credentials['aws_secret_access_key'] = row['aws_secret_access_key']
    return credentials


def get_existant_summaries(user_id):
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name=aws_region)
    try:
        table = dynamodb.Table('summaries')
        summaries = table.scan()
    except Exception as e:
        create_dynamodb_table('summaries')
        summaries = []
    return summaries

def create_dynamodb_table(name):
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name=aws_region)
    # Table definition
    table = dynamodb.create_table(
        TableName=name,
        KeySchema=[
            {
                'AttributeName': 'user_id',
                'KeyType': 'HASH'  # Partition key
            },
            {
                'AttributeName': 'filename',
                'KeyType': 'RANGE'  # Sort key
            }
        ],
        AttributeDefinitions=[
            {
                'AttributeName': 'user_id',
                'AttributeType': 'N'
            },
            {
                'AttributeName': 'filename',
                'AttributeType': 'S'
            },
        ],
        ProvisionedThroughput={
            'ReadCapacityUnits': 10,
            'WriteCapacityUnits': 10
        }
    )
    return table
```

Here is the app.py that I started it:

`app.py`

```
from flask import Flask, url_for, render_template, request, redirect, session, flash
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import FileField
from utils import get_existant_summaries, custom_sort, is_folder, allowed_file
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, url_for
from summarizer import summup
from decouple import config, Csv

SECRET_KEY = config("SECRET_KEY")
UPLOAD_FOLDER = config("UPLOAD_FOLDER")
DATABASE_URI = config("DATABASE_URI")

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = SECRET_KEY
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = DATABASE_URI
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100))

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password


class UploadForm(FlaskForm):
    file = FileField('file')


@app.route('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('login.html')
    else:
        u = request.form['username']
        p = request.form['password']
        data = User.query.filter_by(username=u, password=p).first()
        if data is not None:
            session['user_id'] = data.id  # Stocker l'ID de l'utilisateur dans la session
            session['logged_in'] = True
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
        return render_template('index.html', message="Incorrect Details")
```

I also leave you my DockerFile and my .env

`DockerFile`

```
# Utilisez une image de base Python
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

# Définissez le répertoire de travail dans le conteneur
WORKDIR /app

# Copiez le contenu du répertoire local (contenant votre application) dans le conteneur
COPY . /app

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

# Installez les dépendances de l'application
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Installez python-dotenv pour charger automatiquement les variables d'environnement depuis .env
RUN pip install python-dotenv

# Copiez le fichier .env dans le conteneur
COPY .env .env

# Exposez le port sur lequel l'application Flask écoute
EXPOSE 5000

# Démarrez l'application Flask lors du démarrage du conteneur
CMD ["flask", "run"]
```

`.env`

```
MEANINGCLOUD_API_KEY=1234567890
FLASK_APP=app.py
FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0
BUCKETNAME = bucketname
UPLOAD_FOLDER = uploads
SECRET_KEY=Secret:p
DATABASE_URI=sqlite:///users.db
AWS_REGION=us-west-2
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=id
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=key
```

Comment: I think you should be able to load the .env file when you run the docker command like this: `docker run --env-file .env -p 5000:5000 -v ~/.aws/credentials:/root/.aws/credentials sum_up_app` for example.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @jsn Unfortunately it returns the same message `The security token included in the request is invalid.`

Comment: Okay, so one question is why are you mounting your AWS credentials and then using a .env file for authentication? I would suggest the following tests:

1. Remove the volume mount to the .aws credentials and run again w/ the --env-file command specified. 

2. If this doesn't work, uncomment the session logic in `utils.py`, then directly under that add the following: `dynamodb = session.resource('dynamodb', region_name=aws_region)`. Remove the references from within the `create_dynamodb_table` and `get_existant_summaries` methods. 

Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Update from the frontline: still the same invalid security token when calling the `create_table()` on both approaches 1 and 2. I'm puzzled tough. Why would I need to create a table? To my mind, they are already created in AWS. Thanks for helping me @jsn though. That's very kind.